# int to string concatenation

Tags: python, c, string, int

guys probably this is a silly question, I searched on many sites but my program isn't working :(

I read some values from a MCP3008 connected to a Raspberry Pi and then I send them to PureData using this python script:

```
 os.system("echo '" + value + ";' | pdsend 3000 localhost")
```

where "value" contains the readings from the sensor.
But the script is too slow, so I decide to move to C

```
    int main() {
  for ( ; ; )
  {
    int value = mcp3008_value(0, 18, 23, 24, 25);
    char  message[]="";
    char str[50];
    sprintf( str, "%d", value );
    strcpy(message, "echo '");
    strcat(message, str);
    strcat(message, ";' | pdsend 3000 localhost");
    printf(message);

  }
  return 0;

}
```

but when I execute it I get: Segmentation fault

Is there a simple method to concatenate int and strings like in python?
And do you think that it will be faster than python?

Thanks Guys ;)

Comment: Is `mcp3008_value` a function?

Comment: yes, it's defined in a .h file that I've included ;)

Comment: The system call will not be much faster in c then in python, since python will just turn around and use the c system call.  Have you tried looking at why your python implementation is slow?  For instance `"echo '%s;' | pdsend 3000 localhost" % value` should be faster then concatenating the strings

Answer (score 2):

your line of

```
 char  message[]="";
```

is wrong.

you need to allocate memory for it because it will only allocate 1 byte. You can use the following,

```
 char  message[1000]="";
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
int value = mcp3008_value(0, 18, 23, 24, 25);
char  message[]="";
char str[50];
sprintf( str, "%d", value );
strcpy(message, "echo '");
strcat(message, str);
strcat(message, ";' | pdsend 3000 localhost");
printf(message);
```

can be better (faster, shorter, clearer) written as:

```
char message[512];
const int value = mcp3008_value(0, 18, 23, 24, 25);

sprintf(message, "echo '%d;' | pdsend 3000 localhost", value);
```

That builds the string in a single call. If you have it (I'm not sure about the Pi), you should use `snprintf()` for more protection:

```
snprintf(message, sizeof message, "echo '%d;' | pdsend 3000 localhost", value);
```

But I *seriously* doubt that this bit of processing is where your bottleneck is. It might be the very act of starting (via `system()`) two new processes in order to, in effect, transmit a single integer, that is killing your performance.

Look into other ways of talking to Pd, that don't involve spawning a new `pdsend` every time you want to send something.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs at the line of :

```
strcpy(message, "echo '");
```

because message buffer is only one byte size.